# Almacenar una variable e iniciarla cuando arduino reciba energía

Tags: c++, arduino

Tengo un cronómetro el cual corre bien, reinicio o le deja de pasar energía al arduino mi crónometro empieza desde 0, quiero que empiece con el ultimo valor registrado antes de ser reiniciado. Tengo en mente almacenar el tiempo registrado en una variable pero no se me ocurre como iniciarla de nuevo cuando prendo o reinicio el arduino, este es mi código;

```
//variables
int horas = 0;
int minutos = 0;
int segundos = 0;
int decimas = 0;
long milisegundos = 0;
File myFile;

int pausa = 8;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.clear();
   if(!SD.begin()){
    //Serial.print("No se pudo inicializar");
    return;
   }
}

void loop(){
  myFile = SD.open("TEST.txt",FILE_WRITE);
        if (myFile){

   if(digitalRead(pausa) == HIGH){
    delay(400);

    while(digitalRead(pausa) == LOW);
    delay(400);
   }
    milisegundos = millis();
  if(milisegundos % 100 == 0){ //Only enter if it has passed tenth of a second
    decimas++;
    if(decimas == 10){ //When it has passed 10 tenths of a second it count one second
      decimas = 0;
      segundos++;
    }
    if(segundos == 60){ //When it has passed 60 seconds it count one minute
      segundos = 0;
      minutos++;
    }
    if(minutos == 60){ //When it has passed 60 minutes it count one hour
      minutos = 0;
      horas++;
    }
```

Comment: Hola, ¿Cuanto mide la información que deseas (en KB) guardar y que micro estas usando (Uno, Mega, mini, etc)?

Comment: estoy utilizando una memoria microsd para almacenar la información, estoy utilizando el nano

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la librería EEPROM, la placas Arduino tiene una zona para leer y escribir. Sin necesidad de utilizar un soporte externo.

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

//Crea un objeto con una variable long
struct miObj {
  Long miTiempo;
};

//Usa la posicion 0 para guaradar dicha variable
int dir = 0;

void setup() {
   miObj miMiles;


   //Para recuperar la variable usa en el setup
   EEPROM.get(dir, miMiles); //miMiles contiene el valor long guardado
}


void loop() {


//Crea una instacia de miObj
miObj miVar = {
    milisegundos; //Esta es la variable de tiempo que quieres guardar
};
   //En la parte del codigo que deseas guardar el tiempo
   EEPROM.put(dir, miVar);


}
```

Comment: Tienes que verificar en que parte guardas los datos, calcula que cada operación demora aprox. 3 ms. si lo haces continuamente (me refiero a la grabación del dato) tendrás demoras en tu cronometro.